# private-bower behind blocking proxy. what exceptions are needed?

Tags: git, proxy, bower

We are going to install a [private-bower](https://www.npmjs.com/package/private-bower) repo in a company network, which is behind proxy and blocks all non-whitelisted requests outside. What hostnames do we need to include in the whitelist for the repo to work correctly?

As far as I can tell, it accesses http://bower.herokuapp.com/packages/ when searching for public packages. For both public and private packages the repo will return git endpoints addresses which are then accessed from the client (therefore no need to be whitelisted for the server). The repository also accesses git repos to load package information, meaning it needs access to github. Is that all? Are bitbucket and other git services used as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you simply go to http://bower.herokuapp.com/packages (without the trailing '/') you can see everything that's in the public index and see for yourself - the most used git service is `GitHub` but `BitBucket` and `Gitlab` are also in use.
Many of the packages actually point to a git endpoint with `http/https` and not `git://` if you need to whitelist these as well.

Note that there are also `http/https` that don't point to one of these - but it really depends on whether you will actually need all of that stuff, usually a project will contain only so many packages so I wouldn't worry about stuff you might not need.

On a side note, a service like [Artifactory](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Bower+Repositories) and its [Bower resolver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bower-art-resolver) can save you a lot of hassle as it goes out to (and caches) all of the endpoints and serves whatever's required back to the client. That way you only need to deal with one machine going out instead of all of your clients. Also, I don't think private bower actually downloads the packages for you - looks like it just serves as a registry.

It can also serve as a private repo and index so you don't have to go outside your network at all for your internal stuff(can also have an 'offline' repo for your approved packages that all clients download from instead of having them reach outside for it).